# Filter DetailsList

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Can anyone please let me know how to filter a DetailsList? For instance, let’s say I have the following list:

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiQ0M.jpg)

How do I filter the list such that when I type “Reject”, it will only show items with Status “Reject”

Here is the code I tried (from the documentation https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/detailslist):

```
private _onChangeText = (text: any) => {
    this.setState({ items: text ? this.state.items.filter(i => 
    i.Status.indexOf(text) > -1) : this.state.items });
}

<TextField
  label="Filter by name:"
  onChanged={this._onChangeText}
/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kevintcoughlin/pen/EpzJqz?editors=1011) where I'm filtering a collection of items to see if the text is present in any of the item's values (case-insensitive). It is similar to the documentation example you linked in your original question. I hope that helps!

```
let COLUMNS = [
  { 
    key: "name", 
    name: "Name", 
    fieldName: "Name", 
    minWidth: 20, 
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  { 
    key: "status", 
    name: "Status",
    fieldName: 'Status',
    minWidth: 20, 
    maxWidth: 300
  }
];


const ITEMS = [
  {
    Name: 'xyz',
    Status: 'Approve'
  },
  {
    Name: 'abc',
    Status: 'Approve'
  },
  {
    Name: 'mno',
    Status: 'Reject'
  },
  {
    Name: 'pqr',
    Status: 'Reject'
  }
]

const includesText = (i, text): boolean => {
  return Object.values(i).some((txt) => txt.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1);
}

const filter = (text: string): any[] => {
  return ITEMS.filter(i => includesText(i, text)) || ITEMS;
}

class Content extends React.Component {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: ITEMS
    }
  }

  private _onChange(ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, text: string) {
    let items = filter(text);
    this.setState({ items: items });
  }

  public render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fabric.Fabric>
          <Fabric.TextField label="Filter" onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} />
          <Fabric.DetailsList 
            items={ items } 
            columns={ COLUMNS }              
          />        
      </Fabric.Fabric>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Content />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Figured it out. Is it possible to filter by checking values in just one column instead of all the column values? For example, with your current code, if I type 'A', it will return all the items with value 'A'. Let's say one item's Name is 'abc' and Status is 'Reject', it will return that as well. Instead of that, how would I just check 'Status' column values and return result based on that? Thanks!

Comment: You can accomplish the above by adjusting the filter function like so https://codepen.io/kevintcoughlin/pen/XBwLgp?editors=1011

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help!